# Want to combine different files of Beamer Latex

Tags: beamer

I have multiple beamer latex chapters. I want to combine them in one file so that the equation number and figure number show chapter wise.

Answer (score 1):

Example for the equations (same for figure/table/...):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\begin{frame}{chap1}
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^2
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\section{bar}
\begin{frame}{chap2}
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^2
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```